# getText returning null value on a TextView

Tags: android

I've a TextView in my app with no initial value. This TextView is updated with Firebase `dataSnapshot` value. Now,the problem is this TextView is returning null value even when it has been updated with datasnapshot value. 
My logic is, I need to compare my previous value updated in TextView with new `dataSnapshot` value. If both value differs,i need to send a notificaton. 
So How can i get TextView value from a TextView which is updated with Firebase `dataSnapshot`?
Or what could be the easiest approach for achieving it?

Edit:

Here's my code

```
  //This view is initialised in onCreate. Adding just for reference
  TextView tv= view.findViewbyId(R.id.mytextview);

  mFirebaseDatabaseInstance.getReference("mgs").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //    Log.d(TAG, "App title updated");

                TextView tv= getActivity().findViewbyId(R.id.mytextview);
                String newValue = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);

                tv.setText(bhaw);       

            if (!newValue.equals(tv)) {

                sendNotification("msg");

            }
```

Comment: Can you please post your code to understand your problem and provide the solution !

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya added code

Comment: I'm not sure but the TextView should be Casted! `(TextView) findViewById(id)`

Comment: I tried adding 
                    TextView tv= getActivity().findViewbyId(R.id.mytextview); in onDataChange, but it gives forceclose in the app.

Comment: What are you using here. I mean it is implemented in Fragment or Activity?

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya in a fragment

Comment: @AAShakil it is deprecated. Also, it doesn't matters AFAIK.

Comment: So, you are required to initialize the textview by its view. Let me post a answer with example for you to get clear idea.

Comment: In your code, you declare `TextView tv` but later use `mytextview`, why ? You need to `tv.setText(bhaw)`, this is the name of the variable, not the id of the component. As far as I know, this seems to set the value to a different component so you never set a value to `tv`. FYI: `if (!newValue.equals(tv)) {` will compared the `String` with the instance `TextView`, not his content. Use `if (!newValue.equals(tv.getText())) {`.

Comment: This should be a compile error  if (!newValue.equals(tv))  . How can you compare a String and a TextView ?Should be if (!newValue.equals(tv.getText().tostring()))

Comment: [`Object.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) accepts an `Object` @khetanrajesh ...

Comment: i'm using setText in variable only(tv). i wrote the code manually so did a typo. Kindly ignore that mistake @AxelH

Comment: And are you sure the event is fire at list once ?

Comment: @AxelH onDataChange is called everytime if value gets changed or Activity is initialised

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for initializing text view.

**Fragment.java**

```
public class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

TextView tv;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demo, container, false);
    return view;
}

 @Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tv = view.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
  }
}
```

This is how the initialization of text view is done. You require initialize the textview by the view of fragment. Like this **tv = view.findViewById(R.id.mytextview);** from the object of View class in onViewCreated() method.

You are trying to initialize the text view by context, that's the reason you are facing this issue.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Just edited my code in OP,my bad. Yes, i'm initialising by view.findviewbyid in onCreateView.      getActivity().findviewbyid i've it in dataSnapshot method.

Comment: So you are not required to re-initialize the textview again in onDataChange() you can directly use the textview by its object in whole fragment. Such as tv.setText(bhaw).

Comment: Yeah,that's what my question is. It returns null value. Since this view is initialised in onCreate, it's value is null at that point. So, if i get the value in onDataChange method, i get nul value. That's why i tried "re-initialising " it in onDataChange method